# SQL: constraint enforcing at least one && maximum one for each key

Tags: mysql, constraints, conditional-statements, minimum

My table schema is:

```
 r(int aID not null, int bID not null, bool main)
```

Primary key (aId, bID). Both aID and bID are foreign keys (referring to different tables).

I want to enforce that for every aID, there is always one and one only bID that is also main=true.

How can I do that in db level?
I can enforce the "max 1" by adding a `constraint unique (aID, main)`, and main is either true or NULL.

How about the "at least 1" part?

PS: Working on MySQL.

Edit: Example data for clarification:
You can have various combinations of aID and bID, but for each aID only one combinations shall also have main=true.
Demo data:

```
 1, 2, true
 1, 3, NULL
 1, 4, NULL
 1, 5, true <- wrong, only one main=true
 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create two triggers. Both of them will be applicable for each row. The first will be applicable before insert and the second will be applicable before update. If main=true and there is at least one other row in the table with the same aID as new.aID but with different bID, also with main = true, set new.main = false.

You can do this in a single trigger in most of the RDBMSs, but MySQL doesn't support (if I am not mistaken) triggers applicable for both insert and update.

Comment: Perhaps I didn't explain it correctly, see updated original post. Thank you!

Comment: I understand, I will edit my answer, its second version will be more helpful, at least I hope so.